Firebase Analytics not functioning after switching from CocoaPods to SPM
I recently switched my project from CocoaPods to Swift Package Manager (SPM), and since then, Firebase Analytics has stopped functioning properly. While I can track events in debug mode (by adding "-FIRDebugEnabled" to the scheme), removing debug mode ("-FIRDebugDisabled") results in tracking ceasing to work entirely. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Additionally, the console logs indicate that Firebase Analytics is running properly, and I've already added the -ObjC flag as shown in the image.
enter image description here
